# How to convert this PDE into ODE for numerical solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I ran into this PDE
$$-u_t+a x u_x+(1-b y)u_y+\frac{1}{2}xy u_{yy}+\rho x^2\sqrt{y}u_{xy}=0$$
with initial condition $u(0,x,y)=\phi(y)$ independent of $x$.

Can anyone recognize it and provide some hint on how to deal with it? It will be very helpful if this can be reduced to some ODE's that can be solved numerically. Thank you.